# TypeError: a bytes-like object is required not 'str'

Tags: python, sockets

```
import socket 
connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
connection.connect(("192.168.152.140", 4444))


connection.send("\n[+] connection established.\n")

connection.close()
```

Comment: You have not stated what your problem is. Please give us information about what you're trying to do and what is going wrong

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```py
connection.send("\n[+] connection established.\n".encode())
```

This should work

Answer (score 1):

Your connection.send argument needs to be bytes, but you're passing a string. You should encode it before sending e.g. message.encode('utf-8')

```
message = "\n[+] connection established.\n";

connection.send(message.encode('utf-8'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The `socket.send` function expects bytes, not a string ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.send))

You need to convert the string to bytes before sending: https://www.askpython.com/python/string/python-string-bytes-conversion

It should probably look like this:

```py
connection.send("\n[+] connection established.\n".encode("utf-8"))
```